# Makefile : include in loop / loop outside targets

Tags: makefile

In my makefile I want to include some other makefile depending on a variable in a for loop, Is it possible.

Top Makefile :

```
CC          = gcc
CFLAGS      = -O0 -g3 -W -Wall -pedantic
LDFLAGS     =

DEFINES     =
PROJECT     = proj

INCLUDES    =
SOURCES     =

TEMP_PATH   := $(PROJECT)
include $(TEMP_PATH)/Makefile

$(for blocks in $(BLOCKS); do \
    include $$(blocks)/Makefile; \
done)

all : $(PROJECT).exe

$(PROJECT).exe :
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(DEFINES) $(INCLUDES) $(SOURCES) -o $@

clean :
    rm -rf *.exe
```

proj/Makefile :

```
CC          =   gcc
CFLAGS      = -O0 -g3 -W -Wall -pedantic
LDFLAGS     = 

DEFINES     =  

BLOCKS      := std_communication

INCLUDES    := $(INCLUDES) -I $(TEMP_PATH)/Utils
INCLUDES    := $(INCLUDES) -I $(TEMP_PATH)/Communication

SOURCES     := $(SOURCES) $(wildcard $(TEMP_PATH)/Utils/*.c)
SOURCES     := $(SOURCES) $(wildcard $(TEMP_PATH)/Communication/*.c)
SOURCES     := $(SOURCES) $(wildcard $(TEMP_PATH)/main.c)
```

The for loop syntax seems to be wrong outside of loop.

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Foreach-Function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot write it like that, but you can just write:

```
include $(addsuffix /Makefile,$(BLOCKS))
```